# Need help in Java Array<> libgdx

Tags: java, libgdx

When I change the values of a item of Array<> after assigning it to a temporary variable, the main variable values also changes.

```
Array<Cards> cards = new Array<Cards>();

//add items to cards

Iterator<Cards> iterator = cards.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
      Cards c = iterator.next();
      Cards Temp = c;
      //when I change values of temp...the value of c also changes
      //overall changing the value of cards
}
```

Is there any way I can change the value of Temp and not c or cards?

I am currently making a game in libgdx for Android.

Comment: Clone/Deep copy? http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-deep-clone-example-source-code

Answer (score 5):

You need to make a copy of the object referenced by `c`. What you're currently doing is simply creating another reference to the same object. Depending on the the `Card` implementation and your needs, you can do a `clone` or create a new `Card` explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

By calling the `.clone()` method you can get a copy of the `Object` rather than a reference to it.

As @CharlesDurham said :

> `.clone()` will produce a shallow copy, it's a new instance of Card but if c has any object references the new Card will have the same references as c, Unless you implement the Cloneable interface, then you can implement deep cloning.

```
Array<Cards> cards = new Array<Cards>();

//add items to cards

Iterator<Cards> iterator = cards.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
      Cards c = iterator.next();
      Cards Temp = c.clone();
      //when i change values of temp...the value of c also changes
      //overall changing the value of cards
}
```

Alternately you can make a `new Cards(c)` like so:

```
Array<Cards> cards = new Array<Cards>();

//add items to cards

Iterator<Cards> iterator = cards.iterator();
while(iterator.hasNext()){
      Cards c = iterator.next();
      Cards Temp = new Cards(c);
      //when i change values of temp...the value of c also changes
      //overall changing the value of cards
}
```

Comment: NOTE about this method.
You'll get back what's known as a 'shallow' copy. Yes it's a new instance of `Card` but if `c` has any object references the new `Card` will have the same references as `c`. Edit: Unless you implement the `Cloneable` interface, then you can implement deep cloning.